# Is there a way to clean the console history in Linux for Python?

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I know you can use this but it only clears the screen of the console. Is there a way to clean the whole history?

```
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('clear')
clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is only for linux, by default you'll use bash, so you can delete the file .bash_history

So you can

```
rm ~/.bash_history
```

or even

```
history -c
```

through the terminal (or os.system('...'))

Answer (score 0):

Remove the file `.python_history` located in your `$HOME` directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the python history using python, use should use this snippet:

```
import os

homePath = os.getenv('HOME')
homePath += '/'

fileName = '.python_history'

with open(homePath + fileName, 'w') as myFile:
    myFile.write('')
```

If you want to clear the bash history, rename `fileName` variable to `.bash_history`

Answer (score 0):

import os

homePath = os.getenv('HOME')
homePath += '/'

fileName = 'usmonov__m_'

with open(homePath + fileName, 'w') as myFile:
myFile.write('')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).